# Multiple attributes of same type fail when using Ninject's BindFilter<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, ninject

As part of a identity-enabled authorization system, I'd like to use IAuhtorizationFilter and Attributes to restrict access to action methods in my controllers. I've got things working very well, partly due to help from the following resources:

- [Ninject Binding Attribute to Filter with Constructor Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305476/ninject-binding-attribute-to-filter-with-constructor-arguments)
- https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations
- [Custom Authorization MVC 3 and Ninject IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572257/custom-authorization-mvc-3-and-ninject-ioc/5572752#5572752)
- https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters

However, when I try to decorate an action method with more than one of my attributes, I get an exception as follows (sorry for the formatting):

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]

System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +2691369
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax.c__DisplayClass15`1.b__14(IContext ctx, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:379
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax.c__DisplayClass12.b__11(IContext ctx) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\FilterBindingSyntax\FilterFilterBindingBuilder.cs:358
   Ninject.Parameters.c__DisplayClass6.b__4(IContext ctx, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Parameters\Parameter.cs:60
   Ninject.Parameters.Parameter.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Parameters\Parameter.cs:88
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:97
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.c__DisplayClass2.b__1(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:81
...
```

Here is a very simplified version of my code that demonstrates the problem in an MVC3 app:

**Attribute:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Guid typeId;

    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }

    public SampleAttribute(bool IsAllowed)
    {
        this.IsAllowed = IsAllowed;

        this.typeId = new Guid();
    }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)typeId;
        }
    }
}
```

**Filter:**

```
public class SampleFilter : IAuthorizationFilter, IMvcFilter
    {
        private bool isAllowed;

        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public SampleFilter(bool isAllowed)
        {
            this.isAllowed = isAllowed;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!isAllowed)
                throw new Exception("unauthorized");
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Sample(true)]
        [Sample(false)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

The controller method above works as expected if one or the other of the `Sample` attributes on the `Index()` method is removed. Having both in place, generates the exception. I realize that in this simplified example, there isn't a situation that would call for both attributes, but it's simply for illustration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of Ninject 2.2. Please use 3.0 instead.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/ReleaseNotes.txt

Comment: Thanks, Remo. I appreciate the info and I'm impressed with how quickly you respond to posts here. Thank you.

Comment: I am still having the same problem with 3.0.0-rc3 from NuGet. I created a new sample project following the same concept as above and I get the InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains more than one element". Any ideas?