# Ninject dependency into AuthorizationAttribute MVC4 Web API RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom authorization attribute, required only for some actions, which checks the request headers for a custom token. The token is checked in a database. Checking the database requires access to a service which I would like to have injected through the constructor.

The way I have read this can be done ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572257/custom-authorization-mvc-3-and-ninject-ioc/5572752#5572752), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193414/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-filter-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc/6194159#6194159), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839293/asp-net-mvc3-actionfilterattribute-injection/8317248#8317248)) is by having a constructor-less filter and injecting the dependent one like this:

```
kernel.BindFilter<MyAuthorizeFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<MyAuthorizeAttribute>();
```

However the BindFilter method is not available to me as I have setup Ninject as described [here](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api). This is using **Ninject.Web.Common** instead of **Ninject MVC3** as I read that Ninject MVC3 would not work with MVC4 RC. How else can I go about accomplishing this?

I have read also that I could add to GlobalFilters.Filters - however I don't want it to be present on every action.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Having same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Sorry - I did not solve it! In the constructor for my auth attribute I'm providing an instantiation to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I see how you have set up your application, but my experience has been that if you want a filter for a *WebApi* controller you need to add it to the `HttpFilterCollection` that is available from the `GlobalConfiguration.Filters`. This is a **Different** set of filters than what MVC uses (through the `GlobalFilterCollection`).

Comment: Hi Chris. I'm not sure I follow - in my Global.asax there is no property of GlobalConfiguration called Filters. I can Access GlobalFilters.Filters. Or GlobalConfigurationFilters though! However - I would've thought this does not help me in this scenario as I mentioned that I do not want to apply this filter to every action - only to some.